# What does “euphoniae gratia” mean in the English version of the fundamento?

Tags: fundamento

The 16th rule of the English version of the fundamento is:

> 16. The *a* of the article, and final *o* of substantives, may be sometimes dropped *euphoniae gratia*, e.g. *de l’ mond'o* for *de la mond'o*; *Ŝiller’* for *Ŝiller'o*; in such cases an apostrophe should be substituted for the discarded vowel.

What does *euphoniae gratia* mean? I notice that in the French version it does not appear.

Comment: It's not in the German, Russian, or Polish versions, too.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

The expression stems from Latin (with ablative *grātiā* "with favour" + genitive forming a secondary adposition) and means literally "for the sake of euphony [pleasing sound]", so on the one hand in order to avoid a hiatus (*de l**a a**kvo* → *de l' akvo*), and on the other hand in order to save a syllable (like in the examples you give) or generate a rhyme in poetry.

Comment: You might want to add that it is Latin.

Comment: Thanks for the hint, I added an explanation. As usual, I ask English native speaker to edit my post, if necessary.